# Does Spark support Encryption at Rest?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Hadoop has recently introduced Encryption at Rest (HDFS-6134). I'd like to know whether it's also supported in Spark? I mean can Spark processes data which is stored in encrypted format in HDFS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Spark will be able to access data without any changes to the application code. The data is encrypted transparently to the applications, which means all your Java APIs and command-line interfaces work as before without any changes. The framework will take of encryption without bothering you.

Here is a quote from the documentation:

> HDFS implements transparent, end-to-end encryption. Once configured, data read from and written to HDFS is transparently encrypted and decrypted without requiring changes to user application code.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/TransparentEncryption.html

You will however be required to add/modify some configuration.  [Here's a worked example.](http://hortonworks.com/kb/hdfs-transparent-data-encryption/)

See also blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/01/new-in-cdh-5-3-transparent-encryption-in-hdfs